# Null entry for parameter Id/Can't add data from other model into view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to learning asp.net and I'm trying to output table data from two different tables in one view. I'm getting the following error

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'Vidly12.Controllers.CustomerController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

This line of code is triggering the error

```
@Model.MembershipType.MembershipName
```

in the Details.cshtml
I can't figure out how integrate this table and its data into table. The MembershipName outputs correctly in the CustomerView.chtml so it's associating the customer to the membership name correctly for that view, but not in the Details.cshtml view. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if any additional information is needed

[image]

Details.cshtml

```
@model Vidly12.Models.Customer

    @using Vidly12.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>

<ul>

    <li>@Model.MembershipType.MembershipName</li>
  <li>@Model.BirthDate</li>
</ul>
```

CustomerController.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Vidly12.Models;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using Vidly12.ViewModel;

    namespace Vidly12.Controllers
    {
        public class CustomerController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDbContext _context;
            public CustomerController()
            {
    _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            }
            public ActionResult CustomerView()
            // GET: Customeriew(int id)
            {
                var customer = _context.Customer.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();

                return View(customer);
            }

            public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                var customer = _context.Customer.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

                if (customer == null)

                    return HttpNotFound();

                return View(customer);



            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Customer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly12.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MembershipType.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly12.Models
{
    public class MembershipType
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public string MembershipName { get; set; }
        public byte Duration { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

CustomerView.cshtml
[image]

Comment: No that line is not causing the error. The error is caused because the URL you are calling in the address bar, calls the `Details` method of the `CustomerController`. That method is expecting an `int` and you are not passing it. That error would be in your cshtml that is calling that action method.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `@Model.MembershipType.MembershipName` - its because your calling the `Details(int id)` method but you not passing a value for `id`

Comment: Best guess is in the `Index.cshtml` view, you have a link to call that method but are not passing a value. You need to show the relevant code

Comment: I see why you are saying that since the image doesn't have the /1 or other id number. That line is the issue though. It works without it and with it, I get the two images I just added above Also CustomerView.cshtml and Details.cshtml are the main html pages in question. There isn't an index.chstml page. It opens the CustomerView and then you select the customer and it takes you to the Details.cshtml page. See additional image as reference.

Comment: Check the value of customer in this line to see if there is a customer and the property is also not null: `var customer = _context.Customer.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();`

Comment: If I remove the MembershipName line and click the customer from the CustomerView.cshtml. The Details.cshtml populates @Model.Name with the customer's name and their birthday so it sees the customer value

Comment: @Andy see my answer

Comment: bro, you changed the whole question by deleting the print screen of the argument exception you were getting at first. now my answer is pointless useless so i'll have to delete it. bad move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Details.cshtml` view, you have this line of code:

```
@Model.MembershipType.MembershipName
```

But you are passing this as the model to the above view:

```
var customer = _context.Customer.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

The `MembershipType` property is null so you are getting the error. You need to do this to eagerly load the `MembershipType` property:

```
var customer = _context.Customer.Include(
    c => c.MembershipType).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

Comment: Thank you CodingYoshi! I've been stuck on this for awhile now.